# Can I open and edit a specific layer in Camera Raw?

Tags: software, raw, photoshop, layers, adobe-camera-raw

While editing [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/tushar_mahule/5858609614/), which was shot in JPEG, at one point some noise got added to the sky after I increased the saturation. I knew that the luminance noise reduction in ACR would take care of this. However to do so, I had to save the file as a JPEG and then open it again through ACR, apply noise reduction and then replace the monument with it's layer in the older .psd file (since I didn't want to loose it's detail).

So, I was wondering if there was a way to open a layer directly in Camera Raw and then process it then and there to avoid all this hassle?

Answer (score 2):

After you make your adjustments in ACR, press Shift and then instead of Open Image, you'll see Open Object.  That will create the layer as a smart object and you can then go back to ACR from that smart object layer.  I believe you'd have to have known to do that from the start.  I'm not aware of anyway to reopen a layer in ACR after the fact if you haven't opened it as a smart object.

Comment: In preferences you can set ACR to always open images as smart objects if you're going to do it a lot.